# Facebook Like Button doesn't Publish

Tags: facebook, button, facebook-like

I have this snapshot version of a website and I'm using the new like button, at least trying to.

The like system is working great. I can even save how many clicks on each like I have. 
BUT, I couldn't figure out why every time I try to publish (using the dialog opened after clicking on the like button), the content doesn't appear on my activity or any where else.

That's the example code I'm using:

```
<fb:like layout="button_count" href="http://www.podeir.com.br/brasilia/agenda/visualizar/id_agenda/2/AERO-GROOVE" send="false" width="194" show_faces="false" font="tahoma"></fb:like>
```

Just noticing: My Like Button Count is growing.

Comment: After resolving the problems mentioned on the debugger, the problem looked to be resolved. But now it's unstable, sometimes it works and sometimes don't. Any other tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook tells you what your problem is in the [debugger results](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.podeir.com.br%2Fbrasilia%2Fagenda%2Fvisualizar%2Fid_agenda%2F2%2FAERO-GROOVE).

Your `og:image` tag needs to be a fully qualified URL (e.g. start with `http://`)

Comment: Fixing the og:image problem totally resolved my problem. Thank you again.

Comment: Don't forget to mark this as resolved. (Click the white check next to this answer so it turns green).